# .Htaccess detec Google Chrome

Tags: .htaccess, google-chrome

I need to **detect Google Chrome** in **.htaccess** and forbidden access to it.
I got something but it needs some fix:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^Chrome
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

It has got one bug - It's blocks everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a negation (!) before Chrome and also you're telling UA string begins with Chrome. I didn't tested it but I think it is something like this:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Chrome
    RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Comment: Look http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Chrome/. Chrome never is the first word in the UA string, so second solution will work (I hope).

Comment: Ok but second rule must be "RewriteRule .* - [F]"

Comment: You're right I was wrong with this sorry. I edited the answer.